# I have to describe the functioning of HEVC in few words

Tags: codec, hevc, h.265

> It works by comparing different parts of a video frame in order to find the ones that are redundant within the subsequent frames. These areas are replaced with a short information, describing the original pixels.

Is this correct? How would you describe it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

if I did understand you correctly, you are asking about the general video encoding scheme, so yeah the question is not related to programming and you should google about some video encoding basics.
somehow your definition is right, but very wide. compression in general aims to remove redundancy in bit stream, thus replacing some part of it with shortest segments. in video encoding (avc, hevc or other) the encoder will try to remove special and temporal redundancy. the compression process in complicated and differ from encoder to other so you cannot describe hevc in just one paragraph.
just start looking to the hybrid video encoder, than inter/intra predication+ entropy coding , which are mainly the most important parts.